# g-signin2 is not working with webapp2 (google app engine, users.get_current_user())

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, google-signin

So, this is the sample python code:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users

class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
       #getting the email through a http call from the frontend
        email = json.loads(self.request.body).get("email")
        user = users.get_current_user()
        print "incoming: ", email, user
```

The "email" prints correct signed-in user (which implies my g-signin2 is working) but "user" variable is null (which implies webapp2 is not understanding who's logged in)

Following is my HTML code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id"
      content="<myclientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<google-sign-in-button button-id="uniqueid" options="options"></google-sign-in-button>
```

Following is my angular directive (mostly irrelevent to this problem, but anyway just adding this to be sure):

```
app.controller('GoogleCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {

$scope.signOut = function () {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
};

$scope.options = {
    'onsuccess': function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var profile = response.getBasicProfile();
        data = {
            id: profile.getId(),
            name: profile.getName(),
            imageUrl: profile.getImageUrl(),
            email: profile.getEmail()
        }
        $scope.commsApp(data)
    }
}


//communication
$scope.commsApp = function (data) {
    console.log("sendToApp; data: ", data);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        data: data
    })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log("success. response: ", response);

            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("failure. response: ", response);
            });
    };
}]);
```

I'm able to pass on the profile information to my backend that is obtained when the user logs in through g-signin2 default button. But, when I use users.get_current_user(), I don't get any profile information. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing 2 different authentication mechanisms:

- the [Users Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/)
- the [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

The fact that a user signed in using `google-signin` on some application *outside your GAE app* and placed some maybe correct info (from that external app's point of view) into the request body doesn't mean that user is also signed in *into your GAE app* which uses `users.get_current_user()` from the Users API.

For `users.get_current_user()` to not return `None` the user must properly login at the URL obtained via `users.create_login_url()`.

Comment: Thank you. Got it working. Which of these is better? I see that the webapp2 login takes user to a different screen and reloads, whereas g-signin2 does it without redirection (which I think is better).